# How to properly quote an inet value in PDO::Execute?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

The following works:

```
$db=$this->database;


$query="SELECT blacklisted FROM userip_blacklist "
    . "WHERE ip_addr <<= inet "
    . $db->quote($IP);

$result=$db->query($query);
```

This does not:

```
$query='SELECT code FROM userip_greylist WHERE user_id = ? '
    . 'AND ip_addr <<= inet ? '
    . 'AND expires > now()' ;
$queryvars=array($id,$ip);
    $sth=$db->prepare($query); // This still works
$result=$sth->execute($queryvars); // This generates the error.
```

I'm seeing this in the logs:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$2"
LINE 1: ...dr FROM trusted_ips WHERE user_id=$1 AND ip_addr <<= INET $2
```

I know I'm probably missing something obvious, but what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax with a type name followed by a string value (e.g. `inet '10.0.0.1'` or `interval '10 days'`, refered to as *type 'string'* in [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)) cannot be broken down in a prepared statement with the type being part of the query and the value being a parameter. That's a limitation of this particular syntax.

The generic solution is to use an explicit `cast` instead:

```
$query='SELECT code FROM userip_greylist WHERE user_id = ? '
    . 'AND ip_addr <<=  ?::inet '
    . 'AND expires > now()' ;
```

and pass the IP address as a string literal parameter.

It may also be written as `CAST(? AS inet)` if you find it more readable or more standard.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clearing that up, I was starting to wonder if I was going insane. :)

Comment: Update: `?::inet` didn't work, `CAST(? AS inet)` did. Accepting now.